# Custom add to cart button to add multiple product into cart with quantity :woocommerce

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to create custom add to cart button to add my 3 product into cart with 2 quantity for each..

For add three product into cart I have done using like this:

```
<a id="buy" class="single_add_to_cart_button shop-skin-btn shop-flat-btn alt" href="#">ADD MY PRODUCT</a>
```

$p_id = my product id eg: 45,99,152

```
 <script>    
    jQuery('#buy').click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault(); 
    var myStringArray = [<?php echo $p_id; ?>];
    var arrayLength = myStringArray.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
     addToCart(myStringArray[i]);
    }

    return true;
         });

    function addToCart(p_id) {
     $.get('/glassful/?post_type=product&add-to-cart=' + p_id, function() {
    $(".show_success").show();
     });

    }
    </script>
```

It will add my resulted product into cart but with only 1 quantity
Please let me know how I can add quantity? I want to add 2 quantity of each product.

Mean when click on add to cart three product will added to cart with 2 quantity each.

Thanks for help in advance..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass quantity in query string like:

```
?post_type=product&add-to-cart=100&quantity=2
```

I have modify your code

```
 <script>
    jQuery('#buy').click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault(); 
    var myStringArray = [<?php echo $p_id; ?>];
    var arrayLength = myStringArray.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
     addToCart(myStringArray[i],2);
    }
    
    return true;
     
    });
    
    function addToCart(p_id,qu) {
     $.get('/?post_type=product&add-to-cart=' + p_id +'&quantity='+qu, function() {
     // success
    $(".show_success").show();
     });
    
    }
    </script>
```

I think this will solve your problem.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, it always skips one or more products. It's like the requests are too fast. What could it be?

Comment: @flowDsign if it skips some products then you need add some delay time for every request. If you will add 1 sec or 2 sec delay inside for loop for addToCart(myStringArray[i],2); then it will work

Comment: it doesn't work with the delay. I've removed the `for` loop all together and made a count with a variable using ajax success function to have more control after each request and also when it reaches the maximum number.

Comment: I actually need to increase the quantity from 1 to 90.  Is this really the only way?

Comment: You cannot use /glassful/?post_type=product&add-to-cart= for more then 1 product as your request will be blocked my Woo. It's protection to not overload DB. Better idea is to send products ID to wp ajax hook. I've added answer below

Answer (score 4):

Please check this link , This is works for me :)

[WooCommerce: Allow adding multiple products to the cart via the add-to-cart query string](http://dsgnwrks.pro/snippets/woocommerce-allow-adding-multiple-products-to-the-cart-via-the-add-to-cart-query-string/)

functions.php

```
function woocommerce_maybe_add_multiple_products_to_cart() {
    // Make sure WC is installed, and add-to-cart qauery arg exists, and contains at least one comma.
    if ( ! class_exists( 'WC_Form_Handler' ) || empty( $_REQUEST['add-to-cart'] ) || false === strpos( $_REQUEST['add-to-cart'], ',' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Remove WooCommerce's hook, as it's useless (doesn't handle multiple products).
    remove_action( 'wp_loaded', array( 'WC_Form_Handler', 'add_to_cart_action' ), 20 );

    $product_ids = explode( ',', $_REQUEST['add-to-cart'] );
    $count       = count( $product_ids );
    $number      = 0;

    foreach ( $product_ids as $product_id ) {
        if ( ++$number === $count ) {
            // Ok, final item, let's send it back to woocommerce's add_to_cart_action method for handling.
            $_REQUEST['add-to-cart'] = $product_id;

            return WC_Form_Handler::add_to_cart_action();
        }

        $product_id        = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_product_id', absint( $product_id ) );
        $was_added_to_cart = false;
        $adding_to_cart    = wc_get_product( $product_id );

        if ( ! $adding_to_cart ) {
            continue;
        }

        $add_to_cart_handler = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_handler', $adding_to_cart->product_type, $adding_to_cart );

        /*
         * Sorry.. if you want non-simple products, you're on your own.
         *
         * Related: WooCommerce has set the following methods as private:
         * WC_Form_Handler::add_to_cart_handler_variable(),
         * WC_Form_Handler::add_to_cart_handler_grouped(),
         * WC_Form_Handler::add_to_cart_handler_simple()
         *
         * Why you gotta be like that WooCommerce?
         */
        if ( 'simple' !== $add_to_cart_handler ) {
            continue;
        }

        // For now, quantity applies to all products.. This could be changed easily enough, but I didn't need this feature.
        $quantity          = empty( $_REQUEST['quantity'] ) ? 1 : wc_stock_amount( $_REQUEST['quantity'] );
        $passed_validation = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', true, $product_id, $quantity );

        if ( $passed_validation && false !== WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, $quantity ) ) {
            wc_add_to_cart_message( array( $product_id => $quantity ), true );
        }
    }
}

// Fire before the WC_Form_Handler::add_to_cart_action callback.
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'woocommerce_maybe_add_multiple_products_to_cart', 15 );
```

and you can use for your link.

```
$product_ids = implode( ',', array( 1, 2, 55 ) );
$url = esc_url_raw( add_query_arg( 'add-to-cart', $product_ids, wc_get_checkout_url() ) );
```

Thanks !

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13584405)

Comment: @JFMeier Thanks , I will Add script here :)

Answer (score 3):

Save products id in array and make ajax request

```
 jQuery("#addSelected").click(function() {  var arrayLength =
 arrayOfAddedProducts.length;   jQuery.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: ajaxurl,
         data: {action : 'add_item_from_cart','getIDtoAdd' : arrayOfAddedProducts},
         success: function (res) {
            wc_load_all_products();
         }
     }); });
```

function.php

```
function add_item_from_cart() {
   foreach ($_POST['getIDtoAdd'] as $productId) {
      WC()->cart->add_to_cart( intval($productId), 1, 0, array(), array() );
    // WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id = 0, $quantity = 1, $variation_id = 0, $variation = array(), $cart_item_data = array() );
   }
}

add_action('wp_ajax_add_item_from_cart', 'add_item_from_cart');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_add_item_from_cart', 'add_item_from_cart');
```

Comment: The original way to add multiple products at a time. Thanks