# Add to cart button with quentity filed using woocommerce_before_main_content hook

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to add a cart button and quantity before content. I am using this hook but not working

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_main_content',
           'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30);
```

if i want add to cart button under image use this hook

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails', 
            'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
```

give me the following error

> Cannot redeclare print_attribute_radio() (previously declared in /opt/lampp/htdocs/lifeformchairs.com/wp-content/plugins/wc-variations-radio-buttons-master/templates/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php:17) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/lifeformchairs.com/wp-content/plugins/wc-variations-radio-buttons-master/templates/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php on line 26

Answer (score 0):

Add-to-cart action is executed inside content-single-product.php like this:

```
<?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_single_product_summary hook
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_title - 5
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_price - 10
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_excerpt - 20
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart - 30
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_meta - 40
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_sharing - 50
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' );
?>
```

here the number describes priority of particular action executed.

you can change this priority by removing it and adding it like this in function.php file of your theme:

```
/** woocommerce: change position of add-to-cart on single product **/
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 
           'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 
        'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 9 );
```

Add-to-cart Button now should show after title and before price as its priority is 9.

[Code Reference](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/114734/how-to-customize-position-of-add-to-cart-of-woocommerce-on-product-page)

Comment: But i want another add to cart button Means two button will be in single page @jatin

Comment: you can add this custom code for it : [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32471381/custom-add-to-cart-button-to-add-multiple-product-into-cart-with-quantity-wooco)